# Alduin's Bane quest bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started playing the Dawnguard DLC before I finished the main quest line - I was right before that point where I had to find the Elder Scroll to defeat Alduin.
As I was playing the DLC, I got a bug where when taking the (Dragon) Elder Scroll, it disappeared, so I had to use a command to get it. That started the quest Alduin's Bane. I then finished the DLC, did a few side quests, and realized my mistake. When I travel to the Throat of the World to talk to Paarthurnax, he starts speaking, then stops after his monologue, and nothing else happens.

**Is there is a way to set it back to the mission before Alduin's Bane without losing my progress?**

Answer (score 1):

### Use console commands to fix it:

Alduin's Bane has the Quest ID '*MQ206*'.

1. **Make a save game** of your current state using the Main Menu (not a quicksave).
2. **Find out what quest stage you're currently in** by typing in `Player.sqs MQ206` in the console.
   This will show you a list of the stages of the quest. If there is a `1` behind a certain stage, it means you passed that stage; if there's a `0`, you haven't.
3. **Find the last quest stage you have completed** (the highest number with a `1`), and note down that respective quest stage number.
4. Still in the console, **enter the command** `SetStage MQ206 <quest stage #>`, where `<quest stage #>` is the number you noted down during step 3.
   Your character has now entered a stage earlier in the quest.
5. **See if the quest works properly now**.

   If not, repeat the steps, incrementally replacing `<quest stage #>` with a stage number one step higher/earlier from the one you found in step 3 (e.g. `10` instead of `20`) , until the quest completes successfully.

In your specific case, I assume your character's current stage is `10` (where the objective tells you to "*Read the Elder Scroll at the Time-Wound*"). Preceding quest stages are `0`, `1` and `5`.
Try `SetStage MQ206 5` first, and see if that works.
If not, try setting it to `SetStage MQ206 1`, and otherwise to `SetStage MQ206 0` (make sure you still have the Elder Scroll at that point though).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, you could revert back to an old save before you got the Elder Scroll, you could use a command to finish the main quest, but I'm not sure if you'd want that. The best thing for it is to simply revert back to an old save.

Comment: It's not a great idea to preface an answer with "I'm not sure"...

Comment: Unless you're not sure about it. In that case, it's a good idea.